# Error in processing JSON using jq (specified in buildspec.yml) when running codepipeline

Tags: sonarqube, aws-codebuild

We are trying to integrate sonarqube with CI/CD pipeline. If the quality gate check fails, then the build has to fail. We are getting below error when running status check using jq

****[Container] 2021/11/23 10:58:47 Running command if [ $(jq -r '.projectStatus.status' result.json) = ERROR ] ; then $CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING -eq 0 ;fi**

**/codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: 4: /codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: 1: not found****

Could someone help in fixing this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdC0o.png)

Below is the buildspec.yml file.

pre_build:
commands:
- echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
- $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION)
build:
commands:
- wget 
- apt-get update && apt-get install -y lcov
- apt-get install -y jq
- unzip sonar-scanner-4.6.2.2472-linux-caratlane.zip
- export PATH=$PATH:./sonar-scanner-4.6.2.2472-linux/bin/
- sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=<proj_key> -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.host.url=
- sleep 10
- curl <sonarqube_api_to_get_quality_gate_check> > result.json
- cat result.json
- if [ $(jq -r '.projectStatus.status' result.json) = ERROR ] ; then $CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING -eq 0 ;fi
- echo Build started on `date`
- echo Building the Docker image...

Comment: It's permission issues. You can make the script executable and then retry

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).